# ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT after API call

Tags: php, android, html, api, retrofit

**Here is the scenario:**

- I have more than five live websites on a shared hosting (and multiple
  folders of expried websites).
- Server side pages are in PHP and
  HTML (bootstrap+css).
- No framework is used (Nor codeigniter nor
  laravel). Plain PHP.
- Plus I call different PHP pages from my multiple mobile apps (used by very few people = less than 25 [yes the number of users is very less]).
- Backend database is MySQL.
- The data called by api is hardly in KB (with urls).
- I have got this issue on mobile data (4G) + fibreoptic connection.

With a long study duration, I have found that, after API calls from my mobile apps, immediately if i refresh **any page** on my website (on which API is being called), the page gives "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT" at least for 5 seconds to maximum of 1 minute.

**Strange, thing is**, when, subsequent API calls are made through retrofit on same connection (mobile 4G), they get response, while again, at the same time, when I refresh the webpage, this same irritating error message "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT" is shown.

I use to get this "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT" error every now and then.
As this error is shown for few seconds or to maximum a minute or 2, my every complaint at the hosting provider was responded as "no issues detected".
(so the issue of server over-use also gets ruled out.)

To rule out whether this is my connection problem, I have called up any friend / acquaintance and come to know that when they open my web-page on their lease-line, they too see the same error.
(so the mobile data connection error is also ruled out.)

**What could be the problem?**
**Am I missing something?**
**If I am suppose to give additional info, please comment.**

After reading the 1st comment, here is more to scenario:

1. I have already switched the host.
2. On my request, they have also changed my hosting to another physical server.

Comment: I cannot tell if this is a problem that your code is running into, or if this is a problem with another service using your code. Regardless, without any code for us to investigate, there isn't much that we can do to help. Add some logging is the first thing I'd do. If you think this is a host-level issue, you might want to consider switching hosts.